# C# skipping first line of a text file

Tags: c#

here is the code i'm using

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
                {

                    string[] lines = rdr.ReadLine().Split('|');
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(";Re");
                        sb.AppendLine("@C PAMT " + lines[3]);
                        sb.AppendLine("@T " + lines[0]);
                        sb.AppendLine("@D @I\\" + lines[1]).Replace("I:\\", "");
                        sb.AppendLine(lines[2].Replace(";", "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            writer.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
```

All i want is to either skip the first line of the StreamReader or skip the entire first stringbuilder.  I thought the for would do it but it doesnt.

Note:  i'd like to advoid a foreach.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `foreach`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just read the first line and do nothing with it?

```
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
  rdr.ReadLine();
  ...
```

or if you don't want to do that, have an outside variable i and test for i!=0

Comment: Correct me if I'm missing something, but that's exactly what JaredPar said except that it won't handle the case of an empty file.

Answer (score 20):

Why not justn add the following line immediately after creating the `rdr` variable?

```
if ( !rdr.EndOfStream ) {rdr.ReadLine();}
```

Comment: That would be my first guess, yes.

Comment: yes but i need to do this for the all lines not just the 2nd line

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
if(z > 0)
{
  // All of your sb.Append stuff
}
```

EDIT:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)) 
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs)) 
{  
    bool passedFirstline = false;
    while (!rdr.EndOfStream) 
    { 
        string[] lines = rdr.ReadLine().Split('|');
        if(passedFirstLine)                     
        { 
            sb.AppendLine(";Re"); 
            sb.AppendLine("@C PAMT " + lines[3]); 
            sb.AppendLine("@T " + lines[0]); 
            sb.AppendLine("@D @I\\" + lines[1]).Replace("I:\\", ""); 
            sb.AppendLine(lines[2].Replace(";", "\r\n"); 
        } 
        else
        {
            passedFirstLine = true;
        }
    } 
} 

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create)) 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs)) 
{ 
   writer.Write(sb.ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: His for loop is inside of the while...that seems wrong to me - I'm doubting his code even works.  I'd think there would be end of file errors.

Comment: @rball: Well unless he had more than 3 lines. Then because nothing would ever advance rdr, his while would be infinite. Let me edit and suggest something better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it more times in your program then it's maybe a good idea to make a custom class inherited from StreamReader with the ability to skip lines.

Something like this could do:

```
class SkippableStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    public SkippableStreamReader(string path) : base(path) { }

    public void SkipLines(int linecount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
        {
            this.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

after this you could use the SkippableStreamReader's function to skip lines.
Example:

```
SkippableStreamReader exampleReader = new SkippableStreamReader("file_to_read");

//do stuff
//and when needed
exampleReader.SkipLines(number_of_lines_to_skip);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that not everyone is a fan of using the continue keyword, but in cases like this I almost like it because of the readability. You could change the following code to use a continue:

```
string[] lines = rdr.ReadLine().Split('|');
{
    if (z == 0) continue;   // Skip first line

    sb.AppendLine(";Re");
    sb.AppendLine("@C PAMT " + lines[3]);
    sb.AppendLine("@T " + lines[0]);
    sb.AppendLine("@D @I\\" + lines[1]).Replace(@"I:\", "");
    sb.AppendLine(lines[2].Replace(";", "\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)) 
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs)) { 
  rdr.ReadLine(); // skip the first line
  string line = null;
  while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    string[] lines = line.Split('|');
    sb.AppendLine(";Re"); 
    sb.AppendLine("@C PAMT " + lines[3]); 
    sb.AppendLine("@T " + lines[0]); 
    sb.AppendLine("@D @I\\" + lines[1]).Replace("I:\\", ""); 
    sb.AppendLine(lines[2].Replace(";", "\r\n"); 
  }
} 

if (sb.Length == 0) return; // return if nothing was processed

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create)) 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs)) 
{ 
    writer.Write(sb.ToString()); 
}
```